# When to use command line client in RTC source control?

Tags: clearcase, rtc

Is there any functionality that can be achieved using the command line that is not available using the RTC Eclipse plugin ?

Some users have a natural preference for command line over gui based operations but is there any real advantage using the command line over GUI based operations in RTC source control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scm command isn't complete, especially regarding build (covered by the Jazz Build Toolkit)

But *most* of the operations can be done through the  [Plain Java Client Libraries (PJCL)](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/3.0.1.1?p=allDownloads#plainzips)

And *all* operations should be accessible through https REST queries, following OSLC.

See "[Integrating and Extending Rational Team Concert (the SDK)](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/RtcSdk20)", and
"[Resource Oriented Work Item API with OSLC_CM 1.0](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/ResourceOrientedWorkItemAPIv2)".

[image: Core API]

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'm missing something but PJCL and OSLC seem to target two different sets of operations. PJCL is targeted at build operations and OSLC is targeted at work items operations?

Comment: @user470184 OSLC should be all-encompassing: basically any operation you are doing through the GUI client or full RTC client should be translated into an OSLC web request: creating a Stream, adding a component, managing a workspace... only pure source control operations are specific to `scm` (or `lscm`: https://jazz.net/library/article/620)